# Changing the View for a ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to implement the MVVM design patern for mt WPF application. In order to connect the view to the viewmodels, I use a `ResourceDictionary` (used in `Application.Resources`), that looks like

```
<DataTemplate DataType={x:Type viewmodel:SampleViewModel}>
    <view:SampleView1 />
</DataTemplate>
```

The view models are then simply put into content presenters to display them.

Now, when the user presses a button, I'd like to display `SampleViewModel` using a different view. How do I change the data template used for `SampleViewModel`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Less words more code.
As far as you said, you have the class `SampleViewModel`. I added the property `Title` for demonstration and `ViewType` for identifying the correct view:

```
public enum ItemViewType { View1, View2 };

public class SampleViewModel 
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ItemViewType ViewType { get; set; }
}
```

The `DataTemplateSelector` for two views depending on the `ViewType` property:

```
class ItemViewTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate View1Template { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate View2Template { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var vm = item as SampleViewModel;
        if (vm == null)
            return null;

        switch (vm.ViewType)
        {
            case ItemViewType.View1:
                return View1Template;
            case ItemViewType.View2:
                return View2Template;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Xaml code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="view1Template">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="Red"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="view2Template">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Title}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <local:ItemViewTemplateSelector x:Key="viewTemplateSelector"
                                    View1Template="{StaticResource view1Template}"
                                    View2Template="{StaticResource view2Template}"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="ChangeView" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Command="{Binding SwitchViewCommand}"/>
    <ContentControl  Content="{Binding ItemViewModel}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource viewTemplateSelector}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

The main part is in the class `MainViewModel` where I've put the logic for switching views:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.ItemViewModel = new SampleViewModel { Title = "Some title", ViewType = ItemViewType.View1 };

        this.SwitchViewCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
        {
            this.ItemViewModel.ViewType = this.ItemViewModel.ViewType == ItemViewType.View1
                                            ? ItemViewType.View2
                                            : ItemViewType.View1;
            //The magic senquence of actions which forces a contentcontrol to change the content template
            var copy = this.ItemViewModel;
            this.ItemViewModel = null;
            this.ItemViewModel = copy;
        });
    }

    public RelayCommand SwitchViewCommand { get; set; }

    private SampleViewModel itemViewModel;

    public SampleViewModel ItemViewModel
    {
        get { return itemViewModel; }
        set
        {
            itemViewModel = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ItemViewModel");
        }
    }
}
```

The `SwitchViewCommand` can be any type of command, I use the command from the mvvmlight library.

Inside the handler of the command I change the type of viewmodel and update the property `ItemViewModel` in a tricky way because a `ContentControl` refreshes a view only if to change the Content property, and this property will not be changed unless you set a reference to different object.

I mean, even the code `this.ItemViewModel = this.itemViewModel` will not change the view.
It's strange, but the workaround doesn't require much work.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the mapping by placing a similar resource lower down in the tree. Since WPF will resolve the resource by searching upwards, such an override will replace your existing mapping.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in many different ways depends upon the architecture you want.

- You can write a custom DataTemplateSelector and use it on ContentControl.ContentTemplateSelector and choose those two templates appropriately
- If this pattern of changing the view occures in many different places and more frequent UX, I would also recommend those two views toggled using a DataTemplate.DataTrigger based on a property in SampleViewModel [I am guessing you might have a distinguishing property in the ViewModel to know that state]