# MVVM - Presentation Model in Flex vs Presentation Model in Silverlight: advantages and disadvantages?

Tags: silverlight, flash, apache-flex, model-view-controller, mvvm

As it is said here:

http://houseofbilz.com/archives/2010/12/29/cross-training-in-silverlight-flexmvvm-vs-presentation-model/

"If you do a Google search today for “MVVM and Flex”, the first post is by somebody who claims that MVVM is not a good fit for Flex. I couldn’t disagree more. Out of the box, the Flex framework makes it much easier to implement a Presentation Model than similar MVVM implementations in Silverlight. That is not to say that there aren’t good third-party libraries that make it easier in Silverlight, but without any help, it is easier to do in Flex. "

So MVVM as LOGICAL CONCEPT can be implemented in both but the way it is implemented in Silverlight requires more Plumbing than Flex.

What prevents Silverlight MVVM to be implemented like Flex ? Doesn't Silverlight have same capability in event system to do the same ?

If yes why does Silverlight do things more complicated what's the advantages then ? Is it about using Class Interfaces which are more strongly typed ?

What are the disadvantages also ? For example as for implementing MULTIPLE VIEWS for 1 View-Model does Flex implementation make it also more obvious ?

Comment: The author of that article seems to not know about DependencyObjects, so I'd be a bit leary of his opinions (not that I've ever done more than the most simple SL applications).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What prevents Silverlight MVVM to be implemented like Flex ?

in .net silverlight/wpf everything should transparent. Binding is notification mechanism so, it should act "at least" like event base system.

> If yes why does Silverlight do things
>   more complicated what's the advantages
>   then ?

for me, it is about mindset, if i know it is an event base system, then i should carefully use it. do not over use it, etc.

cases: Binding converter, easily implemented in flex, not in silverlight.

in flex: `text="{getColor(pm.customerName)}"` yes it is amazing simple, but the question is are you sure your PM will be released correctly by garbage collection, because it is an event base system, who responsible to observe the change? `getColor` method? or `text` property? or both? really hard to know that.

in silverlight: `text="{Binding CustmerName, Converter={StaticResources nameToColorConverter}}"` i don't need to ask who is responsible to observe, because colorConverter is only a converter supported by binding. i don't need to worry about memory leak.

so, for me its all about the mindset.

Comment: thank for this thoughtfull answer that's what I'm looking for - understanding the fundamentals. but I'm not very technically literate : why in second case "because colorConverter is only a converter supported by binding. i don't need to worry about memory leak". I don't really grasp it.

Comment: imagine in flex how you observe change made by method, the complete code in flex: in your `getColor()` method you should specify [Bindable('customerNameChange')]. so how the observable is work actually here? in silverlight converter is a simple object not observable, no need to worry about memory leak.

Comment: at least if `[Bindable('customerNameChange')]` above `getColor()]` method doesn't mean that flex observe the `getColor()` method, it easily confused programmer. what is `[Bindable]` mean.

Comment: If I understand we don't know but internally flex should know and release memory for us ?

Answer (score 1):

There are two things, really that make it more complicated:

- Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged
- Commands

One thing you can do in Silverlight is use the ["Property Weaver"](http://code.google.com/p/notifypropertyweaver/).  It will do something similar to the `[Binding]` tag in Flex as it will automatically take public getter/setters and re-write them with the INPC pattern.

As for commands, wrapping methods in `DelegateCommand`s proves to be a lot of plumbing.  There are several approaches to this.  I like a convention-based approach, where you declare a public method named `Execute_Something` and the command `Something` is automatically created for you to bind to.  [Here](http://houseofbilz.com/archives/2010/05/08/adventures-in-mvvm-my-viewmodel-base/) and [Here](http://houseofbilz.com/archives/2010/05/14/adventures-in-mvvm-my-viewmodel-base-silverlight-support/).

Finally, binding in Flex is expression-based where as binding in Silverlight is purely declarative.  I have some ideas for when we get C# v.Next and we might be able to do expression-based binding pretty easily.

Comment: Thanks for the answer so we need to get next C# Huh! Could you also comment about my last question on MULTIPLE VIEWS :)

Comment: What if you do MVVM from scratch without using INotifyPropertyChange if it seems so complicated  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612263/implementing-mvvm-from-scratch-without-using-inotifypropertychange ?

Comment: MVVM without INPC is not really an option.  You need it to have a realistic two-way communication.  As for v.Next C#, we have seen that we will get C# as a service, which means we can do eval.  With that, we can hook up some attached properties with code in it and manage our own binding system.  Don't expect it from Silverlight or WPF, though.  It will have to be grown as an OSS project or something...

Comment: I don't understand "Don't expect it from Silverlight or WPF, though. It will have to be grown as an OSS project or something" ?