# Commands in WPF UserControls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, command

I'm just trying to understand WPF and MVVM and I am totally confused.
Actually I need help with the following task:

I have a MainWindow, that carries a menu. From this menu, I want to load some data into a treeview, that is nested inside a usercontrol.

As I learned so far, I should use commands.
Where do I define them?

Assuming I have the menu, I would use '`inside the MainWindow.xaml.<br>
I also would (of course) implement the`Command`-property inside the menu.

The code for Execution should be nested inside a seperate class or inside the codebehind of the UserControl, that needs the data.

This is my Usercontrol:

```
namespace PlcGenerator.Views
{
  public partial class ProjectView : UserControl
  {
    public static RoutedCommand cmdLoadEcad = new RoutedCommand();

    public ProjectView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void CanExecuteCmdLoadEcad(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e) 
    {
        e.CanExecute = true;
    }

    private void ExecutedCmdLoadEcad(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Command executed.");
    }
  }
}
```

Now this is a (reduced) part of the mainWindow:

```
<ribbon:RibbonWindow
x:Class="PlcGenerator.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:ribbon="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PlcGenerator"
    xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:PlcGenerator.ViewModels"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:PlcGenerator.Views"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Loaded="Window_Loaded"
    Closing="ClosingApp"
    Title="Plc Generator" Height="600" Width="1200">
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static views:ProjectView.cmdLoadEcad}"
                    Executed="ProjectView.ExecutedCmdLoadEcad"
                    CanExecute="ProjectView.CanExecuteCmdLoadEcad"/>
</Window.CommandBindings>
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="settingsViewTemplate" DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:SettingsViewModel}">
        <views:SettingsView DataContext="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="projectsViewTemplate" DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:ProjectViewModel}">
        <views:ProjectView DataContext="{Binding ProjectVM, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">

    <ribbon:Ribbon DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
            <RibbonApplicationMenu SmallImageSource="Icons/ApplicationMenu.png">
                <RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Neues Projekt" ImageSource="Icons/NewEntry.png" Command="{x:Static views:ProjectView.cmdLoadEcad}"/>
            </RibbonApplicationMenu>
        </Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
    </ribbon:Ribbon>

        <!-- Fensterinhalt-->
    <ContentControl Margin="5" Content="{Binding}"/>
</DockPanel>
```

Here I get the error, that the command-element is not found, I think because it's not located in the codebehind MainWindow?

So how can I get that command work from MainWindow-Menu inside a separate class or usercontrol?

I'm really off!

**UPDATE** (as mentioned in first comment, I tried to understand the linked answer):

I created a ViewModelLocator:

```
using PlcGenerator.ViewModels;

namespace PlcGenerator
{
    public class ViewModelLocator
    {
        public ViewModelLocator()
        {
            this.ProjectVM = new ProjectViewModel();
            this.SettingsVM = new SettingsViewModel();
        }
        public ProjectViewModel ProjectVM{ get; set; }
        public SettingsViewModel SettingsVM { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I wanted to make it available for all views and controls, so I inserted it into App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="PlcGenerator.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PlcGenerator"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
  <Application.Resources>
    <local:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" />
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

First problem, I wasn't able to get it inserted while it was located in ViewModel-namespace. How does this work?

Now, before doing anything with commands, I'd like to fill the VMs while MainWindow is shown without UserControls, invoking a menu-event. So I wrote the following in codebehind of MainWindow:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new ViewModelLocator();
}

public MnuOpenProject(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //How can I now access the ProjectViewModel (ProjectVM) of the Datacontext?
}
```

In the MnuOpenProject-method, I didn't manage to have any access to DataContext.ProjectVM. How do I create this object inside the VM-locator?

After I solve that, I will go on with commands. Will I then put all the logic, like opening a project inside the Viewmodels?

**NEXT TRY**

*also edited `<DataTemplate...` in the `<Window.Resources...`-section, see above*

Is that the way it has to be?:

```
public partial class MainWindow : RibbonWindow
{
    #region Data
    public ViewModelLocator viewModelLocator;
    #endregion

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new ViewModelLocator();

        viewModelLocator = (ViewModelLocator)this.DataContext;

    }

    public MnuOpenProject(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        viewModelLocator.ProjectVM.Name = "ProjectName";
    }
}
```

And also in all other views?

Comment: The commands go in the view model and you bind to them from the view. Please narrow down your question a bit.

Comment: I think I have total chaos meanwhile...  My Goal is a MainWindow with a menu. There a Menuitem fires an event to open a fileopen-dialog and load some project-stuff. I was told to better do that, using commands so I tried to implement them but got confused of scope, where to implement and how to trigger the command and get the result (ViewModel) that is needed by a UserControl, that is nested inside the MainWindow. Meanwhile, I am a bit desperated because the more I search the more different approaches I find.

Comment: Now I am rewriting everything again and again and again. So I need assistance step by step. First, the ViewmodelLocator from the maintained answer looks good as it seems to store my data, available for every view and usercontrol.

Comment: Ok, disregarding the commands... is that the rigth way, that I wrote under NEXT TRY, to get access to that "global" Viewmodel?

Comment: Not exactly. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an instance of the `ViewModelLocator` class using the following resource in the in `App.xaml`:

```
<local:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" />
```

You could then bind the `DataContext` of the window to a property of the `ViewModelLocator` directly in the XAM markup like this:

```
<Window ... DataContext="{Binding ProjectViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" />
```

Using this approach, there is no need to set the `DataContext` programmatically in the code-behind.

Once you have set the `DataContext` to an instance of a view model returned from the `ViewModelLocator`, you can bind to any public property of the view model in the view, e.g.:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SomePropertyInProjectViewModel" />
```

Comment: That instance is created on app-startup, right? So how can I change the properties, and show them in a bound control? As I wrote, I open a projectfile and load e.g. a ProjectName. I'd like to insert this name into the property `ViewModelLocator.ProjectVM.ProjectName`. How do I solve that?

In WindowResource I'm binding the Control like this: `<views:ProjectView DataContext="{Binding ProjectVM, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"/>` and I call the UserControl in codebehind: `DataContext = viewModelLocator.ProjectVM;`

Comment: Yes, it's created on startup. You should just set `this.ProjectName` in the view model. The question is where exactly you want to do this. MVVM is all about moving the logic to the view models and models. There should no code in your code-behind except for view-related logic.

Comment: But when I open the fileopen-dialog, this happens in codebhind. right? So now I have to parallel worlds. The viewmodel and the codebehind. I think I'm too stupid to understand or to explain?

Comment: No. It should happen in the view model. You should probably do some reading on MVVM.

Comment: Oh be asured I've read tons of stuff. Obviously I didn't find the rigth.
So to be sure... I implement a command (however I will solve that) in my viewmodel and then I trigger that and open the filedialog there? If so, I will be back with new questions tomorrow. Perhaps you have a good idea/link to MVVM?

Comment: @Telefisch: Yes, exactly. Please refer to [this](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/06/30/handling-events-in-an-mvvm-wpf-application/) blog post.

Comment: Yes, I‘m always trying to only ask one question but sometimes the problem is a bit diffuse (to a beginner). Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a ViewModel where you define the command if you are trying to use the MVVM pattern. You need to set the DataContext in the View to the ViewModel - if you need help doing this, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33675209/4424781) answer.

Comment: I edited my question so could you please have a look at it?