# Change subview with binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm, view

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Changing the View for a ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309099/changing-the-view-for-a-viewmodel)

I have a view:

```
<UserControl ...>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ComboBox ItemSource="{Binding Items}" />
        **<???>**
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I have ViewModel:

```
public class VM
{
    // ...
    public List<Entities> Items { get; set;}
    public String Title { get; set; }
}
```

and I have a few subview's like this:

```
<UserControl ...>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
</UserControl>
```

When user selecta some value from `ComboBox` in main View, I need to place in second column
of main View some of `subViews`. If user selects other value in `ComboBox`, another `subView` sould replace existing `subView`.

How can it be done?

Comment: If your question is similar to another which I've already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309099/changing-the-view-for-a-viewmodel/5310213#5310213. I can rewrite it so it'll use the combobox for view switching.

Answer (score 1):

I usually just use a `ContentControl` and let it figure out which view to draw based on DataTemplates

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedView}">
    <ContentControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModelA}">
            <local:ViewA />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModelB}">
            <local:ViewB />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModelC}">
            <local:ViewC />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Resources>
</ContentControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could bind to the `SelectedItem` of the `ComboBox`, e.g.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cb" ItemSource="{Binding Items}" />
<ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=cb}" Grid.Column="1">
    <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <v:SubView /> <!-- Bind properties as appropriate -->
        <DataTemplate>
    <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
<ContentControl>
```

If you have differnt views use the [`ContentTemplateSelector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplateselector.aspx) instead of hardcoding one template.